# 1980s/1990s short story: AI generated movies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, computers, actors

Recent news reminds me of a story from the 1980s or 1990s (in *Asimovs*, I think) about people making a movie with real actors as a novelty (as opposed to a movie with computer-generated "actors" as was the practice of the time the story takes place in).

The movie was about a killer (a remake of 'Psycho' perhaps) and the one detail that I remember most clearly is that the actor playing the killer played him as a clumsy person who struggled with opening a can and tripped while pulling on his pants.

This isn't Connie Willis' Remake but it's dealing with the same issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched for klutz and "Isaac Asimovs Science Fiction Magazine" and found the story - it's ["A Star is Born"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42750) by Michael Cassutt, from July 1984, available at the [Archive](https://archive.org/details/Asimovs_v08n07_1984-07/page/n65/mode/2up).

Computer-generated movies:

> "Tell me, lovely Allison, what makes you think anyone does any
> producing or developing in Hollywood any more? That went out with
> backlots and ten percent interest. We have a saying these days:
> 'People don’t make movies, they remake them.’ There are no stories. A
> movie 'star,’ Allison, is just a face ... a reputation . . . raw
> material you can use for a reference tape. Plug the tape into the
> right scanimation program and you can make your dreams come true. Want
> to see Ronald Reagan in Casablanca? Y ou got it. How about J ames Dean
> in Saturday Night Fever? Easy. All you need is some old movies, the
> reference program, and about three million bucks worth of
> equipment.”

A movie with a real actor:

> As for the cast, I phoned Sidney the Agent, who just happened to know
> a couple of out-of-work kids who were modelling and doing small
> theater. That’s where we got our male lead, a piece of prime U.S.
> grade A-1 beefcake named Kent Something.

Playing a klutzy killer:

> I had neglected to script anything to go under the main title and had
> had to improvise a sequence at the last minute without much thought.
> What I had come up with was, I hoped, a nice bit of characterization.
> See, the acetylene torch killer, played by Kent S., had to be
> established right away as a bit of a klutz. Not an
> Oh-God-what-a-pitiful-wretch kind of klutz . . . just your ordinary,
> everyday kind of klutz. I needed it because Kent was hand- some in a
> brittle way and didn’t look much like a guy whose life is not going
> right. So I had asked Kent to fool around in the bachelor-bare kitchen
> of my apartment (it took about a minute to strip it completely) and
> try to open a can of frozen Welch’s grape juice . . . with no
> utensils. It was great. He tried to pry the lid off with his fingernails, then he banged the can against the counter top, and then — to
> suggest that our torch killer might be a bit more unwrapped than the
> average klutz — he bit the can. He kept biting the can until the damn
> thing opened, by which time he had a bloody mouth.
>
> The audience exploded into laughter, even those who knew it was
> coming. From that point on, everything got weird. People laughed all
> the way through the first co-ed slaying and the big chase through the
> streets of North Hollywood, right through the scene where poor
> Allison/Darlene’s shower becomes a steam bath. My first reaction was
> extreme mortification, but Allison squeezed my hand and said, "It’s
> perfect!